# Trouble parallellising on HPC

Tags: parallelization, remote-access, high-performance-clusters

I'm trying to carry out a parallel computation using Mathematica's inbuilt parallel functions, `ParallelTable`, etc. The problem is that the HPC doesn't seem to like my code.

Here is a significantly simplified version of my code (but should get across the issue):

```
LaunchKernels[5];

ParallelEvaluate[

f[x_]:=x^2;

];

table = ParallelTable[{x,f[x]},{x,1,5},Method -> "FinestGrained"];

func = Interpolation[table];

ParallelEvaluate[parafunc[x_] = func[x]];


Print[ParallelEvaluate[NIntegrate[parafunc[x],{x,1,5}],1]]
```

I have written this in a text editor that I have subsequently saved as a `.m` file.

When I run this code the output is simply a Mathematica error stating that the integrand as evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points. I really can't see what I'm doing wrong, as if I just get it to `Print[ParallelEvaluate[parafunc[1.4],1]]` for example, then it correctly gives me the value of `parafunc[1.4]` so the sub-kernels do seem to have access to the function.

Having run tests, it seems to be that for some reason Mathematica on the HPC doesn't get along with `NIntegrate` of the parallelised function `parafunc`.

Are there any subtleties to using `ParallelEvaluate` and `NIntegrate` on an HPC that I'm unaware of here?